# Ignoring blank lines in Sublimerge

Tags: merge, sublimetext3, diff, sublimetext

I'm loving sublimerge. But after looking through the docs I can't find any way to ignore blank lines.

In the image below, you can see a difference indicated by the green and pink arrows. The description just says "Right Line Missing". As you can see, the only difference here is that the file on the right does not have this blank line.

[image]

How can I make sublimerge ignore these blank lines? I've tried just removing all the blank lines in each file using search and replace in sublime and then running sublimerge, and that works.. but this isn't the optimal solution for me as I like having blank lines in between functions, etc.

Comment: If you're using Sublimerge 3, have you tried the `ignore_whitespace` setting?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion OdatNurd. Yes, I have it enabled at beginning and end of line. But it still highlights empty lines

Comment: Same problem here [link](https://i.imgur.com/k3kxiCp.png).
I’ve reported the bug to the issue tracker website !